# The argument type 'Future<bool?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool'

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have a problem with passing a bool value that comes from a bloc. The error that occurs is : "The argument type 'Future<bool?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool'.". I attach my code below. Could someone please help me ?

```
class ChatBadge extends StatelessWidget {
const ChatBadge({
Key? key,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return BlocProvider(
  create: (context) => ChatsBloc(
    chatsRepository: context.read<ChatsRepository>(),
    usersRepository: context.read<UsersRepository>(),
  )..add(
      const GetChats(),
    ),
  child: BlocBuilder<ChatsBloc, ChatsState>(
    builder: (context, state) {
      final badge = context.read<ChatsBloc>().isRead();

      return Badge(
        showBadge: badge,
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.mode_comment_outlined,
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
  );
 }
}
```

My bloc :

```
Future<bool?> isRead() async {
try {
  final user = _usersRepository.currentLoginUser;
  final isRead = await _chatsRepository.findUserUnreadChat(user.id);
  return isRead;
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
return false;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`isRead()` is a future method, you can use FutureBuilder for this.

```dart
builder: (context, state) {
  final badgeFuture = context.read<ChatsBloc>().isRead();
  return FutureBuilder<bool?>(
    future: badgeFuture,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData)
        return Badge(
          showBadge: snapshot.data ?? false,
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.mode_comment_outlined,
          ),
        );
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  );
},
```

More about using [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I still get the error : "The argument type 'Future<bool?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool'." in showBadge :(

Comment: Oh, I've made another typo, forgot to using `snapshot` .try now

Comment: The error has disappeared but it still does not display the Badger improvement next to the chat icon.

Comment: try to check printing `snapshot.data` inside if statement, if it is getting the bool as true.